# PowerShell throws a System.OutOfMemoryException on reading a large (50 MB) XML document

Tags: xml, powershell, memory-management, large-files

We are running the following script:

`[xml]$products = Get-Content C:\fso\products.xml`

and receiving the following error:

> System.OutOfMemoryException

We assume that this is because the XML file is massive. The solution will probably involve reading the XML one line at a time. **How can we process this file? For instance, how can we count the number of elements? Or, how can we print the element names to the console window?**

We are currently looking at this link:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/stephap/archive/2009/05/27/choking-on-very-large-xml-files.aspx

The XML structure is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Products.xsd" generated="2014-01-21T08:21:41">
        <Products>
            <upc>0000000000001</upc>
            <description>BASICS $1.00</description>
            <cost>0.6</cost>
            <normal_price>1</normal_price>
            <pricemethod>0</pricemethod>
            <target_margin>0</target_margin>
            <department>34</department>
            <pack>1</pack>
            <tax>3</tax>
            <foodstamp>0</foodstamp>
            <scale>0</scale>
            <dsd>0</dsd>
            <modified>2014-01-04T10:23:55</modified>
            <cost_modified>2012-11-11T11:20:58</cost_modified>
            <active>1</active>
            <advertised>0</advertised>
            <whomodified>170</whomodified>
            <longdescription>TEAR ISSUE</longdescription>
            <seconddescription>ROLL START</seconddescription>
            <discount>1</discount>
            <wicable>0</wicable>
            <validage>0</validage>
            <deleted>0</deleted>
            <attributes>2056</attributes>
            <Created>2005-02-16T09:53:00</Created>
            <CreatedBy>1</CreatedBy>
            <Points>0</Points>
        </Products>
        <Products>
            <upc>0000000000357</upc>
            <description>CHARMIN BATHROOM TISSUE</description>
            <cost>5.81</cost>
            <normal_price>7.99</normal_price>
            <pricemethod>0</pricemethod>
            <target_margin>0</target_margin>
            <department>4</department>
            <pack>1</pack>
            <size>OVERLIMIT</size>
            <tax>2</tax>
            <foodstamp>0</foodstamp>
            <scale>0</scale>
            <dsd>0</dsd>
            <modified>2010-06-30T23:55:00</modified>
            <active>0</active>
            <advertised>0</advertised>
            <whomodified>30</whomodified>
            <longdescription>CHARMIN BATHROOM TISSUE</longdescription>
            <discount>1</discount>
            <wicable>0</wicable>
            <validage>0</validage>
            <deleted>0</deleted>
            <attributes>2048</attributes>
            <Created>2005-02-16T09:53:00</Created>
            <CreatedBy>1</CreatedBy>
            <Points>0</Points>
        </Products>
```

Comment: I just tried the Get-Content approach on a 1.5GB (yes, GB) XML file. It ended up filling the servers 70GB of memory, and continued on the page file. The conversion to [xml] is an impossible memory hog...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably better to use XPath to query such documents. XPath can often work in a streaming mode which doesn't require the whole document to be loaded into a DOM tree.

See `Select-Xml`:

The following would count all elements in an XML file:

```
Select-Xml -Path C:\fso\products.xml -Xpath "count(//*)"
```

This way you're able to fetch small snippets of the XML you're after or do computations on them.

See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849968.aspx

Comment: This is easier to work with so we marked it as the answer instead.

Comment: @jessehouwing: I'd like more information on using streaming when working with Xpath/Select-Xml. You happen to have any good resources?

Comment: I've tried this method, on my 1.5GB XML file it still used 8GB of memory, but it finished after about 15 minutes. Great performance! Having a way to use streaming would keep the memory usage down...

Comment: It all depends on the type of operation and I suspect also a lot on how you handle the data that you extract. Just creating a massive amount of strings in a fast loop with enough free memory can cause the garage collection to lag a bit, causing higher consumption than strictly needed.

Comment: For true streaming, have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xstreamingelement.aspx. More on teh difference between XPath Document and Xml Document can be found here: http://hashname.wordpress.com/tag/xmldocument-vs-xpathdocument-performance/ and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2011/09/14/effective-xml-part-1-choose-the-right-api.aspx

Comment: Hmmm.... Select-Xml : The file 'my-data.xml' cannot be read: The input document has exceeded a limit set by MaxCharactersInDocument.

Comment: Looks like Select-Xml is limited to 500MB: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35412715/736079

Answer (score 1):

One line at a time is going to be horribly slow on a file that size.

You can use Get-Content -Readcount to process chunks of lines at a time (-ReadCount 1000 will give you arrays of 1000 lines each).

Comment: When running [xml]$products = get-content -ReadCount 1 $xmlPath; we are still getting the System.OutOfMemoryException. What gives?

Comment: You can't cast the result as [XML].  That will only work if you can read in the entire file.  You'll need to read it in as string data and work on it using array operators like -match and -replace.

Comment: This suggestion might be useful if your XML is built out of multiple nodes of the same type, like books, and you parse them out of a buffered reader, and convert them to XML one by one...

Comment: For that kind of scenario, using get-content with -delimiter might be better.  Make the closing node tag the delimiter, and then pipe each segment through foreach-object for processing. Then you don't have to worry about a node possibly spanning two readcount segments.