# Powershell Select-Xml : The input document has exceeded a limit set by MaxCharactersInDocument

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to process a 1.7Gb xml file in PowerShell. I have the following line but it fails:

```
PS C:\data> $badges = Select-Xml -Path .\Badges.xml -XPath "//badges/row[UserId='8152']"
```

But I get the following error:

```
Select-Xml : The file 'C:\data\Badges.xml' cannot be read: The input document has
exceeded a limit set by MaxCharactersInDocument.
At line:1 char:11
+ $badges = Select-Xml -Path .\Badges.xml -XPath "//badges/row[UserId='8152']"
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\data\Badges.xml:String) [Select-Xml], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProcessingFile,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectXmlCommand
```

Any ideas on how to process the file? I should end up with about a dozen or so elements from the file, so the output is quite small compared to the size of the file overall (which has roughly 15 million row elements).

Comment: You'll need to provide more context. This is the first time I've dealt with XML files in powershell so your explanation is incomplete from my point of view. Also, this reads like an answer, not a comment.

Comment: PeterSerAl sometimes has issues with English phrasing and refrains from properly answering in favour of others doing so on occasion.

Answer (score 1):

`Select-Xml` have hardcoded limit `MaxCharactersInDocument` = 536870912 (0.5gb) for loading XML documents from file. It can not process file, which is big as yours. You need to load your XML document yourself, then you can query it with `Select-Xml` cmdlet or `SelectNodes` method.

```
#Load document
$Xml=New-Object Xml
$Xml.Load((Convert-Path .\Badges.xml))

#Select-Xml cmdlet
Select-Xml -Xml $Xml -XPath "//badges/row[UserId='8152']"

#SelectNodes method
$Xml.SelectNodes("//badges/row[UserId='8152']")
```